# How to set startup commands for application´s in launcher shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, command-line, startup, launcher

How can i set startup commands for application´s in launcher shortcut?

Example:
I want to start my Browser with this command:

`opera --disable-reading-from-canvas --disable-webrtc-encryption`

or

`chromium-browser --no-sandbox --disable-reading-from-canvas --disable-webrtc-encryptio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Files as root and go to /usr/share/applications/
[image]

Find the shortcut you need and open it in Scratch and edit the Exec line with whatever you need.
[image]

Some applications setup their .desktop files in ~/.local/share/applications/ so you might want to check that folder too.

Comment: Thank you, I could not found this folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is included by default:  Nothing to install

From the terminal type:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

Then you have the nearly same interface as the settings-applications.
Best of luck.[image]

Comment: Good too know, but this is not the right answer to my question.

startup commands for application´s in **launcher shortcut**